# Print variable with multiple datatypes in F#

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and am trying to print a variable that is a List.map with 3 datatypes (string * int * float) as shown below:

```
let get_metrics (d : Data) (list : (string*string*string) list) =
    let re = rl |> List.map( fun (ida, idb, w) -> (tostr(d.Item(idn)), Convert.ToInt32(d.Item(id)),
                                                  todbl(d.Item(w))*1.0) )
                |> List.sortBy( fun (ida, _, w) -> (-w, ida) )
                |> List.head 
    
    printfn "%A" re
```

When I attempt to printfn with %A I get an error saying "This expression was expected to have type 'string' but here has type 'string * int * float'

I tried using %d and %i but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. If you want to increase the chances of getting help, submit a portion of your code which compiles standalone, including the required types and the `open` for the namespaces you're using.

Comment: `%A` can certainly print a tuple so your error is most probably elsewhere.